# Как сделать поворот компонента TImage?

Tags: delphi-7

Делаю программу рулетка, мне нужно чтобы компонент **TImage** вращался, возможно ли это сделать в Delphi и если да, то как ?

Comment: нет, невозможно

Comment: @Igor , а есть ли какие-то другие способы сделать анимацию в delphi ?

Comment: Создать заранее видео файл и использовать TAnimate, подготовить все картинки (frames) и менять их в событие Timer'a, рисовать на лету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поворот не компонента нужно выполнять, а изображения. Вот [тут](http://zhukovsd.blogspot.com/2010/04/blog-post.html) к примеру как повернуть изображение с примерами и всей математикой.

Comment: Топик-стареру: также обратите внимание на упоминание GDI+ внизу.